# Method should convert a char to integer but wont work (Java)

Tags: java, char, integer

I wrote a method that should convert a char with the value '3' to '9' into an integer value.
It should compare the ASCII-value of c with 33(3) to 39(9). The only result I get is -1. If you would know a better way to
I appreciate your help but I also want to know where my mistake is. Thanks in advance

```
static int count(char c){
    int i = 33;
    for (int i = 33;i<40;i++){
        if (c == i) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: edit: Forgot the i in my return

Comment: Take a step back and look at your return statements... How many iterations will your loop complete?

Comment: If you want to use this `for` loop, put `return -1` **after** `for`!

Comment: @user3788064 I guess not. The loop returns at its first iteration because of the second `return` statement

Comment: Any reason it shouldn't work for 0, 1, or 2?

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's trying to start from `33` **in decimal**, but the ASCII code for `'3'` is `33` **in hexadecimal**, written as `0x33`.

Comment: Try `Character.getNumberValue(c)` however this will work for all digits, even non ASCII digits.

Comment: @ciuak good point, I though the problem was that it will only ever return the `(int) c` or `-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(c < '3' || c > '9') 
  return -1;             // If ASCII code is not in the range '3' to '9' return -1
else                  
  return (int)(c - '0'); // return ASCII code - '0' code (the number itself)
```

Comment: Why would I return c - '0'?

Comment: ASCII code for `0` is `0x30` and for digit `n` it's `0x3n`. Subtracting `'0'` from that will give you the `n` itself.

Comment: Wow that is a cool little trick. Tank you a lot for the help!

Comment: You don't need a cast to upgrade a char to an int.

Comment: @ikegami you're right, because subtraction auto-casts them to `int`s.

Comment: Even with subtraction. `class a { public static void main(String[] argv) { char c = '!'; int  i = c; } }`

Comment: Java's `char` type holds a Unicode/UTF-16 code-unit (one or two per Unicode character). If you mention ASCII, you'll have to explain that, by design, Unicode is a superset of ASCII and has the same codepoints for the common characters. That's a pretty long line of unnecessary reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Despite your claims, your code doesn't compile! most significantly, you get

```
missing return statement
```

You never get to compare `c` against anything but `33` because you accidentally placed the `return` in the loop instead of outside.

Furthermore, the Unicode code point of `3` is 33<sub>16</sub> (33 hex, aka 51), not 33<sub>10</sub> (33 decimal).

Fixed:

```
static int count(char c) {
    for (int i=0x33; i<0x40; i++){
        if (c == i)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

But you could write that as

```
static int count(char c) {
   return c >= '3' && c <= '9' ? c : -1;
}
```